# CSS changes work in Firebug but not in style.css

Tags: css, buddypress

I am making changes to my style sheet in my child-theme. When I make a change via Firebug they are implemented. When I make the same changes in my style.css file it doesn't work.

I am trying to change the width of the following:

```
    #buddypress #signup_form.standard-form input[type="text"],
    #buddypress #signup_form.standard-form textarea,
    #buddypress .form-allowed-tags,
    #buddypress #commentform input[type="text"],
    #buddypress #commentform textarea {
       width: 80%;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wich changes are not applied? Please provide full example with HTML. Do you reload your page clearing cache?

Comment: The current width is set to 35%. I change the width to 80% in Firebug and it changes. If I then add the same code into style.css and change the width to 80% nothing happens. If I then look in Firebug it shows that new code with a line through it and the original code (at width 35%) still in place. Yes the cache is cleared.

Comment: You wrote : *and the original code (at width 35%) still in place*, then you just wrote: *Yes the cache is cleared*. => It seems not if your original code is still in place. Be sure you don't have another cache (server-side cache) in place.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I have disabled cloudfront for the dev work and all other CSS changes I am making are being implemented.

Comment: Im wondering if it is hardcoded in another file and being overwritten? I have tried width: !important 80%; but that makes no difference... .

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add `!important` as in `width: 80% !important`? What do you see in the HTML / Styles panel of Firebug: is 80% there but overridden by 25%? Then you should write above rule after the one which sets width to 35% or add some specificity to your selector

Comment: That fixed it thanks! I think I just had the CSS the wrong way around!!!! What an idiot! :/ Thanks